# Configure Database Properties for Tomcat Webapp

Tags: tomcat, java, web-applications, springframework

I setup a sample application in Tomcat but have trouble getting the database connection working. It is a standard WAR package written in Spring framework and uses a MySQL database.

The application is the *Granny Address Book* from http://www.cumulogic.com/downloads/sample-applications/.

I have deployed it under `tomcat/webapps/` (Tomcat 7.0.42 with MySQL 5.1.73 running on the same host.)

- Mysql DB name: `grannydb`
- JNDI Name: `MySqlGBDS`

I cannot locate where to place the database connection settings, as it does not have the usual `database.properties` file. The only reference to database settings are in `granny.xml`:

```
<database>
  <engine>MySQL-5.5.27</engine>
  <no-of-nodes>1</no-of-nodes>
  <storage>10</storage>
  <config>
    <master-username>demo</master-username>
    <master-password>demodemo</master-password>
    <port>3306</port>
    <character-set>UTF-8</character-set>
  </config>       <external-host></external-host>
</database>
```

But this file is not packaged inside the webapp (it comes separately,) and it's lacking a database host name.

I tried placing `granny.xml` inside the webapp, under `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/` but it fails to connect to the database.

The current behavior is the webapp is starting but `catalina.out` warns:

```
 WARN : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection
 to query metadata org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException:
 Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Where should `granny.xml` be placed?
What else is missing?

(Yes I did already create the database and user in MySQL. No tables are getting created by the app.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it uses JNDI you need to set up the database connection in either `server.xml` or `context.xml`.

As an administrator it is better to setup the database connection in `server.xml`, otherwise you end up unpacking and packing the WAR-file before each deployment.

Open server.xml. There should be a section called `GlobalNamingResources`. Here you add your database connection.

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"  
          validationQuery="/* ping */"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          name="jdbc/MySqlGBDS" 
          username="<username>"
          password="<password>" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://<ipaddress>/grannydb" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I had solved it using `context.xml` with a `<ResourceLink />` declaration. It's nice to see some extra things I could use there.

Comment: Tomcat 9, Java 11: Putting this in server.xml didn't work for me.  Instead, following the directions at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources and putting it in context.xml did the trick.